# deploying grails application to tomcat 7 or 8 (Same error)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, grails

So I have an application which works fine when deployed locally, When I deploy it to my server it throws the following errors :

```
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/app]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF (Is a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:735)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:863)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Aug 02, 2017 11:01:51 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/app/WEB-INF/lib/el-api-2.1.2-b03.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Aug 02, 2017 11:01:51 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/app/WEB-INF/lib/javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Aug 02, 2017 11:01:51 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/app/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Aug 02, 2017 11:01:51 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/app/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.15.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Aug 02, 2017 11:02:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [net/sf/ehcache/Cache.class] from Jar [jar:jndi:/localhost/app/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-2.10.4.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.readInt(FastDataInputStream.java:145)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Utility.swallowAttribute(Utility.java:86)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Utility.swallowFieldOrMethod(Utility.java:77)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readMethods(ClassParser.java:235)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5413)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Aug 02, 2017 11:02:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/app]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager.getManager(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/res/StringManager;
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.<clinit>(WsWebSocketContainer.java:78)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5514)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue is with this, It's obviously complaining about ehcache further along - These are my dependencies :

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"



    // Custom Dependencies

    // Users and roles
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M1'

    // Recaptcha
    compile "org.grails.plugins:recaptcha:3.0.1"

    // Database
    runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4'

    // Google Viz
    compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-google-visualization:2.0"

    // for doing reports.
    compile "org.grails.plugins:export:2.0.0"
```

I've found out that ehcache is being loaded in by `org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M1`

But I think the main problem is the file not found exception which is thrown on WEB_INF (which is can see is a directory ..)

My grails version is 3.3.0
My gradle version is 3.5

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: how about file permissions on that directory?

Comment: okay so the permissions on the tomcat8 directory is 775, group and user tomcat8. the actual war file I just changed to 777 for the hell of it! The same exceptions still appear but it actually starts processing the WAR now. It's currently failing because these are 'SEVERE' exceptions however I can see it now touching the db and processing fine. Thanks for this.

Comment: The directory is called `/var/lib/tomcat7` and the owner is `tomcat8`? Coincidence? Note this when you change permissions back from 777

Comment: I've switched to tomcat8 now instead of 7, Permissions are now normal not 777. Its deploying but still complaining for the same issues. Thanks

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF (Is a directory) What does `ls -l  /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app/WEB-INF` show is it a folder does it have anything inside it ? what are the permissions on that folder you need to sort out all these issues around the user, its a case of setting it in the config files, use the same user for both then work your way out once you have a shared permissions and correct permission folders

Comment: I'm deploying from a war file, that folder is contained within my war.